# [Typescript][RxJS] Why is there no type error when returning an observable of partial type?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, typescript2.0

For a variable of type `Observable<T>`, I tried to assign an `Observable<S>` where `S` is a partial of `T` and surprised that there's no assignment error during compilation.

Would love to pick your brains to understand the cause of this behaviour.

```
// RxJS 5.3.0
// TS 2.2.2

interface Super {
  a: number;
  b: number;
}

interface Subset {
  a: number;
}

type Maybe<T> = T | undefined;

// Both of the following produce errors
const super1: Super = {a: 1} as Subset;
const superMaybe: Maybe<Super> = { a: 1 } as Maybe<Subset>;

// But this doesn't error
const superObservable: Rx.Observable<Super> = Rx.Observable.of<Subset>({a: 1});
```

Comment: Interestingly if you use typescript@next, it is flagged as an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in fact unrelated to RxJS. This is a TypeScript issue which is already fixed in the future `2.4` version. That's why it works when you install `typescript@next`.

See: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14770